# How can I determine how many hours per employee are overtime hours while using a conditional function like CASE or CHOOSE?

Tags: sql-server

I'm asked to make a view for a bunch of columns coming from a bunch of different tables. [image] You See the OTHours column needs to be created by taking the Workhours data and seeing if it goes over 40 hours. If it does then I take that number and put it into the OTHours column.
Also If there is a holiday in that week that means anything over 32 hours is considered overtime. Here's some sample data [image] How would I do this without using any variables to store the overtime hours since it must be done using a conditional and or some function?

Comment: This looks quite similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003062/how-do-i-qualify-a-column-and-how-can-i-use-a-conditional-function)... Have you attempted anything at solving this yourself?

Comment: @GMB I have an Idea using a scalar variable but this problem is from a previous chapter and requires me to use a CASE or CHOOSE instead. I have no idea how I would take the result data without using a variable though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `CASE` statement like this:

```
select 
  case
    when WorkHours>40 or (WorkHours>32 and HolHours) then WorkHours
    else 0
  end as OTHours
```